Logstash and parsing submessage
I have 3 types of log messages
2024-07-22 11:45:29.125 +02:00 [Information] [EventService] Events generation finished
2024-07-22 11:45:29.125 +02:00 [Information] [Process] Result: "[11:45:29 INF] Generation finished"
2024-07-22 11:45:29.267 +02:00 [Information] [] Worker is stopping gracefully

Now I try to configure logstash for this, I managed to do it for first let us say level that is timestamp [level] [source] and [log_message]. the last one sometimes has a sub message like
"[11:45:29 INF] Generation finished"

So i tried also to add this, but with no luck, my config looks like:
input {
  file {
    path => "/data/logs/**/*.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => [
        "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:event_time} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:timezone} \[%{WORD:level}\] \[%{GREEDYDATA:source}\] %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}"
      ]
    }
  }
  
  # Additional grok pattern to handle sub-message if present
  grok {
    match => {
      "log_message" => [
        '(?m)%{QUOTEDSTRING:sub_message}"(:? %{GREEDYDATA:remainder})?'
      ]
    }
    tag_on_failure => []
  }

  # Parse the sub-message if present
  grok {
    match => {
      "sub_message" => [
        '\[%{TIME:sub_time} %{WORD:sub_level}\] %{GREEDYDATA:sub_log_message}'
      ]
    }
    tag_on_failure => []
  }

  if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    drop { }
  }

  mutate {
    add_field => { "timestamp" => "%{event_time} %{timezone}" }
  }
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"]
    timezone => "UTC"
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "timestamp", "event_time", "timezone" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}

Anything here I am doing wrong?

The pattern used in sub_message : [%{TIME:sub_time} %{WORD:sub_level}] %{GREEDYDATA:sub_log_message} doesn't match wich the log sample you have shared. I mean there is no [ in your sample before the time, everything are ok in sample or regexp?

Try adding different tags on each grok filter and see which grok is failing.
